# Remove style added dynamically from Vaadin Page

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, vaadin

In Vaadin Page is there a way to remove dynamically added style?
I have a switch of css which is implemented with a combo box so a user can select specific style. When style is changed I am adding a new style using:

```
getPage().getStyles().add("some css");
```

However, when user changes the style once again it adds another "style" element. I cannot find a way to remove the old "style" node. Class:

```
public static class Styles implements Serializable
```

from package:

```
package com.vaadin.server;
```

does not provide any method to do that. Is there any solution?

**Edit:**

I was able to solve this problem with a workaround. After changing style to a new one (so new "style" tag is added) I am removing the old one with usage of javascript:

```
getPage().getJavaScript().execute(REMOVE_OLD_STYLE_SCRIPT);
```

This script removes always the "style" tag with index [1] (index [0] has style added from css file which I do not want to remove).

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('style').length > 2) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('style')[1].remove()
}
```

To be honest - it works but I do not like this solution. As I said - it is a workaroud and in my opinion there should be such a function to remove some dynamic styles using Vaadin classes.